# Is it possible to run FindBugs against only one Java class?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, findbugs

I use the FindBugs Eclipse plug-in and was wondering if I can simply analyze only one class rather than the entire project? I can't seem to figure it out. Simply right-clicking on the target class doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @Donal, to be fair, the OP could be working on some super huge project on some slow machine, and doesn't want to wait a long time for FindBugs to run.

Comment: @Peter, exactly. We're working on a HUGE legacy code base and I've added one class, on which I want to be able to quickly run FindBugs.

Comment: @Donal Fellows: FindBugs is focussed on peephole detection.

@Peter Recore: FindBugs runs fine on projects the size of the jdk. You probably aren't going to see many jars bigger than that.

Comment: Actually, I've been greatly enjoying reading about FindBugs this past 20 minutes (rather than watching SO). Wonder what it will find in the codebases I work with...

Comment: @Donal: When you first introduce FindBugs into a legacy project (especially one without unit tests), it's sometimes easier to do a divide-and-conquer and apply it to the most critical classes first.

Answer (score 4):

Simply right-clicking (menu item FindBugs->FindBugs) on the target class work perfect for me.
After performing it - just open FindBug view/prespective. May be you just have no problems in this class? ;)

Comment: how do you do this from the CLI?

Comment: i ran it (findbugs -textui) against .class files and directories of .class files and it just works.